# How to indicate the end of a subheading's content?

Tags: org-mode

Below I show a toy example, consisting of two headings, the first of which contains a subheading:

```
* HEADING 1

  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis
  lobortis, lectus sed tincidunt condimentum, justo ligula vestibulum
  ligula, eget mollis nisl erat vitae turpis.

** subheading 1.1

   Fusce ut auctor purus, vel suscipit nulla. Nulla aliquet lectus ut
   efficitur fermentum. Aliquam placerat sodales neque, sit amet
   ultricies tortor pulvinar et.

  Mauris tincidunt diam nec dui interdum tincidunt. Duis vel augue eu
  eros semper semper et sed augue. Mauris a tellus leo. Pellentesque
  ac erat quis turpis vulputate dapibus.

* HEADING 2

  Curabitur sed nibh sed nibh accumsan aliquet a et quam. Curabitur
  eget semper ante. Vivamus sed velit suscipit, finibus ante in,
  aliquam est. Sed a porttitor est, nec consectetur urna. Suspendisse
  potenti. Aenean pulvinar pretium molestie.
```

Note that the normal text of HEADING 1 both precedes and follows subheading 1.1.  In particular, the paragraph that begins with *Mauris tincidunt diam ...* does *not* belong to subheading 1.1, but rather it belongs to HEADING 1.

Unfortunately, as written above, org-mode will treat this paragraph as part of subheading 1.1.  For example, if I attempt to collapse that subheading, my screen looks like this:

```
* HEADING 1

  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis
  lobortis, lectus sed tincidunt condimentum, justo ligula vestibulum
  ligula, eget mollis nisl erat vitae turpis.

** subheading 1.1...
* HEADING 2

  Curabitur sed nibh sed nibh accumsan aliquet a et quam. Curabitur
  eget semper ante. Vivamus sed velit suscipit, finibus ante in,
  aliquam est. Sed a porttitor est, nec consectetur urna. Suspendisse
  potenti. Aenean pulvinar pretium molestie.
```

...whereas I want it to look like this:

```
* HEADING 1

  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis
  lobortis, lectus sed tincidunt condimentum, justo ligula vestibulum
  ligula, eget mollis nisl erat vitae turpis.

** subheading 1.1...

  Mauris tincidunt diam nec dui interdum tincidunt. Duis vel augue eu
  eros semper semper et sed augue. Mauris a tellus leo. Pellentesque
  ac erat quis turpis vulputate dapibus.

* HEADING 2

  Curabitur sed nibh sed nibh accumsan aliquet a et quam. Curabitur
  eget semper ante. Vivamus sed velit suscipit, finibus ante in,
  aliquam est. Sed a porttitor est, nec consectetur urna. Suspendisse
  potenti. Aenean pulvinar pretium molestie.
```

---

I am thinking of the content under subheading 1.1 as secondary/background/supporting detail for the material under HEADING 1; as such I want to be able to hide it so as not to obscure the main content.  (In a more realistic situation, the content under subheading 1.1 could be much lengthier, hence much more obtrusive, than what I show in the toy example above.  I'm thinking of a functionality similar to the "inline footnotes" one finds in, e.g., [fivethirtyeight articles](https://fivethirtyeight.com/features/donald-trump-had-a-superior-electoral-college-strategy/).)

How can I indicate that subheading 1.1 ends right after the sentence that ends with *ultricies tortor pulvinar et*?

Comment: Related question: [In org-mode how to break current section and escape to upper level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30997099/in-org-mode-how-to-break-current-section-and-escape-to-upper-level)

Answer (score 2):

My spontaneous impression is that you whish for the impossible.

When you start a subtree then everything below belongs to that subtree and can not be directly associated to the parent of the subtree anymore.

Org has inlinetasks though which are delimitted explicitly at the end.

You can create an inlinetask with

```
M-x org-inlinetask-insert-task
```

Possibly they are the right tool for your case.